# Preload cells of uitableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I acknowledge that UITableview load dynamically a cell when user scrolls. I wonder if there is a way to preload all cells in order not to load each one while scrolling. I need to preload 10 cells. Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can initialize table view cells, put them into an array `precomputedCells` and in the data source delegate method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` return the precomputed cells from the array instead of calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. (Similar to what you would do in a static table view.)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return [self.precomputedCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

It might also be useful to have a look at the
WWDC 2012 Session 211 "Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS"
where it is shown how to fill the contents of table view cells in background threads while keeping the user interface responsive.

Comment: As you said i saved the my cells to an nsmutablearray. Then i preload them one by one via [self tableView:tablefollow cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath1]; . The uitableview is not visible at preloading time. After the uitableview is visible i notice that  NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%i-%i", indexPath.section, [indexPath row]];

    UITableViewCell *cell=[aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; is giving me nil! How can i overcome this issue? I guess is because the uitableview is not visible during preloading the cells. Am i right?

Comment: @stefanosn: My idea was not to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` at all. I have updated the answer accordingly. - *It may also be that I misunderstood your question*. I don't think that you can force the table view to actually *load* all cells. Even if you call `[self tableView:... cellForRowAtIndexPath:...];` for all cells, the table view might discard unused cells. You can only *precompute* all cells (as described in my answer) so that loading each cell is done more quickly. - I hope that this helps.

Comment: i was thinking of preloading the cells on the uitableview so that i do not have to return a cell at - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath in order to improve scrolling. So this is not possible right?

Comment: @stefanosn: Yes, I do think that is impossible.

Comment: Well it helped me a lot your advice. Precomputing the cells and save them to an NSMutableArray really helped! The cells load faster when user scrolls but still there is a slight delay when updating the interface. I guess i have to see again the WWDC 2012 Session 211 "Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS" to go one step further updating the right way the interface. If you have any other suggestions let me know. I am going to keep searching about this issue and i will edit the update at my question.

Comment: @MartinR have you had any luck mixing precomputed cells with dequeuing? Seems to give unpredictable results for me.

Answer (score 11):

I was looking for a solution to the original question and I thought I'd share my solution.

In my case, I only needed to preload the next cell (I won't go into the reason why, but there was a good reason).

It seems the UITableView renders as many cells as will fit into the UITableView frame assigned to it.

Therefore, I oversized the UITableView frame by the height of 1 extra cell, pushing the oversized region offscreen (or it could be into a clipped UIView if needed).  Of course, this would now mean that when I scrolled the table view, the last cell wouldn't be visible (because the UITableView frame is bigger than it's superview).   Therefore I added an additional UIView to the tableFooterView of the height of a cell.   This means that when the table is scrolled to the bottom, the last cells sits nicely at the bottom of it's superview, while the added tableFooterView remains offscreen.

This can of course be applied to any number of cells.  It should even be possible to apply it to preload ALL cells if needed by oversizing the UITableView frame to the contentSize iOS originally calculates, then adding a tableFooterView of the same size.

Hopefully this helps someone else with the same problem.

Comment: This looks a nice solution. Unfortunately it doesn't work with paged tables.

Comment: The clue of preloading cells is your solution!

Comment: This is the only solution, to this day. Although this is only a good idea if you know that the height of your table or collection view won't be too big otherwise you'll end up with memory and performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Mark I also changed the height of my UITableView temporarily so that the table view creates enough reusable cells. Then I reset the height of my table view so that it stops creating reusable cells while scrolling.

To accomplish that I create a helper bool which is set to false by default:

```
var didPreloadCells = false
```

It is set to true when my table view first reloaded data and therefore created the first reusable cells.

```
resultsHandler.doSearch { (resultDict, error) -> Void in
    [...]

    self.tableView.reloadData()

    self.didPreloadCells = true

    [...]
}
```

The real trick happens in my viewDidLayoutSubviews Method. Here I set the frame of my table view depending on my boolean. If the reusable cells were not created yet I increase the frame of the table view. In the other case I set the normal frame

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.tableView.frame = self.view.bounds

    if !didPreloadCells
    {
        self.tableView.frame.size.height += ResultCellHeight
    }
}
```

With the help of that the table view creates more initial reusable cells than normal and the scrolling is smooth and fluent because no additional cells need to be created.

Answer (score 0):

Change the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier when you are reusing the table view otherwise it will load the old data

Answer (score 0):

Solution for autoresizing cells. Change 'estimatedRowHeight' to lower value

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 32; //Actual is 64
}
```

Actual estimated height is 64. 32 is used to add more cells for reuse to avoid lagging when scrolling begins