# Keyboard causes UICollectionView Cells loading bug

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I got a funny question: "Can someone explain this behaviour?"

[Click here to view .gif (I'm not allowed to post pictures yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnvd7.gif)

Explanation: When I click on the search bar a new ViewController is being presented (the one you see in the gif). There the keyboard is immediately popping up. When I now dismiss the keyboard by scrolling down it seems like the cells that were behind the keyboard re-render or were not loaded yet... I have no clue where to search for this, so I spared the hassle of posting unnecessary code.

Thanks! :-)

Comment: A gif is hard to debug. Share some code. cellForRow(at:), the way you load data, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with the gif. `UITableView` cells are created and reused when necessary. That is when they become visible or invisible. Since you changed the view controller with the keyboard popped up, only visible cells are created. The ones behind the keyboard are not initialized yet.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I thought and was afraid of. Any ideas how I could fix this? -> "Pre-loading" the cells behind the keyboard?

Comment: This is another question and is really difficult without your code and approach. But I suggest you to have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662450/preload-cells-of-uitableview). Two solutions are proposed and you can check them out. @RedX